# HTML based remote form POST & get remote server HTML response using php curl?

Tags: php, html, forms, curl

I'm making a mirror public exam result publishing site. What i'm trying, user will submit their roll info to my page, I'll post data to original server & bring back original server response to my site.

here is ID's of my HTML form input-

```
    id="sr" name="sr"
    id="et" name="et"
    id="exam" name="exam"
    id="year" name="year"
    id="board" name="board"
    id="roll" maxlength="6" name="roll"
    input id="button2" name="button2" type="submit" value="Submit"
    id="button" name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset"
```

On submit form it call `process.php`

Here is code of process.php I'm trying to make using curl & php based on some class but not working. I'm not curl guy so don't have much knowledge about it.

```
<?php
$post_data['sr'] = '';
$post_data['et'] = '';
$post_data['exam'] = '';
$post_data['year'] = '';
$post_data['board'] = '';
$post_data['roll'] = '';



foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) 
{
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);


$curl_connection = curl_init('http://remotehost/result.php');

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
//curl_close($curl_connection);
var_dump($result);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));

?>
```

How to fix it??